# Can this Delphi 6 bitmap modification code be sped up with SIMD or another approach?

Tags: performance, delphi, optimization, bitmap, simd

I have a Delphi 6 application that modifies bitmaps in real time.  Currently I am using the code shown below to do quickie brightness boost and contrast changes.  If the operation were just an addition or just a multiplication, I could see how SIMD could be used, but since both an addition and a multiplication are involved, and since there is also the Trunc() operation to restrict it to the range of a Byte, I'm not sure if SIMD could be used here.  Here are my questions:

1. Can SIMD be used with this code and do you know of a good code sample I could work from?  What kind of a speed boost could I expect?
2. Would the (potential) padding of the scan lines be a problem?
3. Any general optimization tips on speeding up the code?

;

```
// A fast version of this function would be to only allow range reductions
//  as a power of 2 and then use shl operations instead of divisions.
procedure doBrightnessAndContrast(var clip: tbitmap; compressionRatio: double; shiftValue: Byte);
var
  p0: PByte;
  x,y: Integer;
begin
  for y := 0 to clip.Height-1 do
  begin
    p0 := clip.scanline[y];

    // Can't just do the whole buffer as a big block of bytes since the
    //  individual scan lines may be padded for CPU alignment.
    for x := 0 to clip.Width - 1 do
    begin
      // Red
      p0^ := IntToByte(Trunc(p0^ * compressionRatio) + shiftValue);
      Inc(p0);
      // Green
      p0^ := IntToByte(Trunc(p0^ * compressionRatio) + shiftValue);
      Inc(p0);
      // Green
      p0^ := IntToByte(Trunc(p0^ * compressionRatio) + shiftValue);
      Inc(p0);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using integer arithmetic?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.  Good point.  I'll recast compressionRatio and shiftValue to integer and see what kind of speed improvement I get since I probably won't lose any noticeable fidelity as far as the user's perception is concerned.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, SSE or MMX is possible.

In your case however you may get almost the same speed improvement if you precompute a 256 entry table using your equations.

Then replace all computations with a simple table lookup. My best bet is, that on modern processors this will give nearly the same speed as MMX/SSE.

Comment: I thought about this a bit and want to make sure I understand you.  To fully pre-compute a table, if I recast compressionRatio and shiftValue to Byte and indexed the table by (p0^, compressionRatio, shiftValue) would require a 3-dimensional table that is 256 cubed or 16,777,216 bytes in size which is quite large.  Or were you indicating a different representation?

Comment: No, the idea is to calculate the table outside the loops over the pixels

Comment: @RobertOschler, just pre-calculate the multiplication to start.  That'll get rid of 3 multiplications and three costly Trunc()'s per pixel.  I doubt pre-calc'ing the addition of shiftVal would save you much.